# Create a zero-filled 2D array with ones at positions indexed by a vector

Tags: matlab, octave, vectorization

I'm trying to vectorize the following MATLAB operation:

> Given a column vector with indexes, I want a matrix with the
>   same number of rows of the column and a fixed number of columns. The
>   matrix is initialized with zeroes and contains ones in the locations
>   specified by the indexes.

Here is an example of the script I've already written:

```
y = [1; 3; 2; 1; 3];
m = size(y, 1);

% For loop
yvec = zeros(m, 3);
for i=1:m
    yvec(i, y(i)) = 1;
end
```

The desired result is:

```
yvec =

 1     0     0
 0     0     1
 0     1     0
 1     0     0
 0     0     1
```

Is it possible to achieve the same result without the for loop? I tried something like this:

```
% Vectorization (?)
yvec2 = zeros(m, 3);
yvec2(:, y(:)) = 1;
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two approaches you can use here.

**Approach 1:**

```
y = [1; 3; 2; 1; 3];
yvec = zeros(numel(y),3);
yvec(sub2ind(size(yvec),1:numel(y),y'))=1
```

**Approach 2 (One-liner):**

```
yvec = bsxfun(@eq, 1:3,y)
```

Comment: I particularly like the second approach :)

Comment: Also it appears `yvec` has number of columns equal to the max of `y`, so for the second approach you can have a generalized version as `yvec = bsxfun(@eq, 1:max(y),y)`.

Comment: Or, in octave only, `(1:3) == y` which is approach 2 with [broadcasting](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Broadcasting.html).

Comment: @ederag If MATLAB goes with implicit broadcasting, we would be in luck! :)

Comment: @Divakar You mean like [it did in 2016b](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/)?

Comment: @Wolfie Yup, back then we were hearing news about its arrival :)

Answer (score 5):

Yet another approach:

```
yvec = full(sparse(1:numel(y),y,1));
```

Comment: I didn't know the sparse representation in Matlab but it seems to be really useful in this case!

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
yvec = accumarray([(1:numel(y)).' y], 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way:

```
classes_count = 10;
sample_count = 20;
y = randi([1 classes_count], 1, sample_count); 

y_onehot = zeros(classes_count, size(y, 2));
idx = sub2ind(size(y_onehot), y, [1:size(y, 2)]);
y_onehot(idx) = 1
```