# Create a matrix with ones in specific columns

Tags: matlab

`y` is a column vector with integer values denote label number (say between 1-3).
Now I need to create a matrix with same number of row of `y`. Each row `i` is now a vector with the `y(i)` positioned element to be `1` and the others to be `0`.

Example:

```
y = [3, 2, 2]';

x = [0,0,1;
     0,1,0;
     0,1,0];
```

Is there an efficient way to finish this job. I know a for loop will do:

```
x = zeros(size(y, 1), 3)
for i = 1:size(y, 1)
    x(i, y(i)) = 1
end
```

Comment: Here's an exact duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23078287/create-a-zeros-filled-2d-array-with-ones-at-positions-indexed-by-a-vector

Comment: @Divakar Wow hadn't seen that dupe before. I like the `sparse` solution in there. Very clever.

Comment: Yeah, as it turns out, we had a chain of dups on this particular problem. If I remember correctly, that sparse was the most efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily do this with `sub2ind` which converts subscripts to linear indices. Your row subscripts are `1:numel(y)` and your column subscripts are the values of `y`.

```
x = zeros(numel(y), max(y));
x(sub2ind(size(x), 1:numel(y), y(:).')) = 1;
```

Or you can simply do this with a little index math.

```
x = zeros(numel(y), max(y));
x(((y(:).' - 1) * numel(y)) + (1:numel(y))) = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed.