# Matlab One Hot Encoding - convert column with categoricals into several columns of logicals

Tags: arrays, matlab, statistics, data-analysis

**CONTEXT**

I have a large number of columns with categoricals, all with different, unrankable choices. To make my life easier for analysis, I'd like to take each of them and convert it to several columns with logicals. For example:

```
1   GENRE
2   Pop
3   Classical
4   Jazz
```

...would turn into...

```
1   Pop Classical Jazz
2   1       0      0
3   0       1      0
4   0       0      1
```

**PROBLEM**

I've tried using `ind2vec` but this only works with numericals or logicals. I've also come across [this](https://gist.github.com/zygmuntz/6939718) but am not sure it works with categoricals.  What is the right function to use in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to convert from a [categorical](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) vector to a [logical array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html), you can use the [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) function to generate column indices, then perform your encoding using [any of the options from this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23078287/52738):

```
% Sample data:
data = categorical({'Pop'; 'Classical'; 'Jazz'; 'Pop'; 'Pop'; 'Jazz'});

% Get unique categories and create indices:
[genre, ~, index] = unique(data)

genre = 

     Classical 
     Jazz 
     Pop 


index =

     3
     1
     2
     3
     3
     2

% Create logical matrix:
mat = logical(accumarray([(1:numel(index)).' index], 1))

mat =

  6×3 logical array

   0   0   1
   1   0   0
   0   1   0
   0   0   1
   0   0   1
   0   1   0
```

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. In my case, the data was actually not categorical so I needed to also transform it to string using `cellstr(x)` and then to categorical using `categorical(x)` - after that, your code did the job. Now I just need to loop it over 200+ columns.

Comment: @Sekoul: It sounds like your `x` is a character array? In that case, you don't even need to convert to a categorical. You can just convert to a cell array of character arrays using `cellstr`, then pass that to `unique`.

Comment: Got it, thanks! How would I go about adding the heading to each column? Answers online point at using `array2table` and then using the `genre` var to appoint headings. Would that be appropriate here?

Comment: @Sekoul: Yes, if you want a table instead of just a matrix, you could do `array2table(mat, 'VariableNames', genre)` if `genre` is a cell array of character arrays, or `array2table(mat, 'VariableNames', cellstr(genre))` if `genre` is categorical.

Answer (score 1):

*ind2vec do work with the cell strings, and you could call cellstr function to get such a cell string*.

This codes may help (From [this](https://gist.github.com/zygmuntz/6939718) ,I only changed a little)

```
data = categorical({'Pop'; 'Classical'; 'Jazz';});
GENRE = cellstr(data); %change categorical data into cell strings
[~, loc] = ismember(GENRE, unique(GENRE));
genre = ind2vec(loc')';
Gen=full(genre);
array2table(Gen, 'VariableNames', unique(GENRE))
```

run such a code will return this:

ans =

```
Classical    Jazz    Pop
_________    ____    ___

0            0       1  
1            0       0  
0            1       0
```

you can call *unique(GENRE)* to check the categories(in cell strings). In the meanwhile, *logical(Gen)*(or call *logical(full(genre))*) contain columns with logical that you need.

P.s. categorical structure might be faster than cell string, but ind2vec function doesn't work with it. *unique* and *accumarray* might better.

Comment: Similar to answer above, also a viable solution, thank you!